# how to check the same value or more than one in looping arrays and make new keys as a differentiator on php

Tags: php, arrays

I want to check if the values ​​in the looping array are the same or more than one, with the else conditions too. What kind of conditions should I do?

in the array that I made [title] => Kue Lapis there are two and there [title] => Kue Nastar only one

I found the same question but I want different results from it.

what I want if the value is same or more than one, it will create a new key as [confirm] = true and if not then the key [confirm] = false

this my array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [order] => 127
            [title] => Kue Nastar
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [order] => 128
            [title] => Kue Lapis
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [order] => 129
            [title] => Kue Lapis
        )
)
```

and this result i want

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [order] => 127
            [title] => Kue Nastar
            [comfirm] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [order] => 128
            [title] => Kue Lapis
            [comfirm] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [order] => 129
            [title] => Kue Lapis
            [comfirm] => 1

        )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to loop the array twice.
Once to get the count of each title and once to create the output you expect.

```
// Create associative array of title and count
foreach($arr as $val){
    if(!isset($counts[$val['title']])) $counts[$val['title']] = 0;
    $counts[$val['title']]++;
}

// Add count 1/0 to array
foreach($arr as &$val){
    if($counts[$val['title']] > 1){
        $val['confirm'] = 1;
    }else{
        $val['confirm'] = 0;
    }
}

var_dump($arr);
```

https://3v4l.org/WJVp5

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_count_values`, `array_column` with `array_walk`

```
$tCounts = array_count_values(array_column($a, 'title'));
array_walk($a, function(&$v, $k) use($tCounts){
  $v['confirm'] = $tCounts[$v['title']] > 1 ? true : false;
});
```

Comment: This will be four iterations of the example array because you best it. If the array is larger then it will be more iterations

Comment: @Andreas can you please explain in more details ? How can it be four iteration ? There are only 2 iteration

Comment: You loop once a outer loop. That is one. There is three items in the array, each iteration does another loop of the array (3x1). That means 1+3. Here I add a "1" for each time it it loops, and I get 11 "1"s https://3v4l.org/BGGQg

Answer (score 0):

With built-in functions [array_walk](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php), [array_count_values](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php) and [array_column](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php), you need just 1 line

```
array_walk($arr, function(&$elem, $index, $occurrence)
{
    $elem['comfirm'] = (int)($occurrence[$elem['title']] > 1);
},
array_count_values(array_column($arr, 'title')));
```

Comment: At most 3 times.

Comment: Nope.. Then you don't understand your code. You loop the array with array_walk. Then on each iteration you do an array_column which loops the array, and then you array_count_values that, which is also a loop. With the three item array in question you loop the arrays 9 times, with 3  items in each iteration that is 27 items this code goes through.

Comment: @Andreas, please understand the code again, `array_count_values` and `array_column` are the 3rd parameter of `array_walk`, they execute only once.

Comment: Please check the document of [array_walk](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php)

Comment: There is nothing saying it's only executed ones as I can see. And if it was true, then there should be no reason why this code is so much slower, which it is. But maybe I'm wrong. But either way it's much slower than a traditional loop.

Comment: This function performs almost the same to your answer: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/aad8f8554971adfdfc97bdb0ac53ab721e9d30e7

Comment: When I tested it it was twice as slow.